# tikzpicture has different arrow tip colors in pdf output and dvi output

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, pdf, arrows, dvi

i have the following mwe

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=angle 45,scale=3,ultra thick]
    \draw[help lines] (-.1,-.9) grid (1.1,.1);
    \draw[>=triangle 60,fill=red,draw=teal](0,-0.1)--++(1,0);
    \draw[>=latex,fill=blue,draw=violet](0,-0.2)--++(1,0);
    \draw[>=stealth,fill=blue,draw=violet](0,-0.3)--++(1,0);
    \draw[](0,-0.4)--++(1,0);
    \draw[draw=cyan](0,-.5)--++(1,0);
    \draw[draw=orange](0,-.6)--++(1,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the compiled pdf file is expected as follows,
[image]

but the compiled dvi file have different arrow tip color,
[image]

after commenting one line

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=4pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=angle 45,scale=3,ultra thick]
    \draw[help lines] (-.1,-.9) grid (1.1,.1);
    \draw[>=triangle 60,fill=red,draw=teal](0,-0.1)--++(1,0);
    \draw[>=latex,fill=blue,draw=violet](0,-0.2)--++(1,0);
    \draw[>=stealth,fill=blue,draw=violet](0,-0.3)--++(1,0);
    % \draw[](0,-0.4)--++(1,0);
    \draw[draw=cyan](0,-.5)--++(1,0);
    \draw[draw=orange](0,-.6)--++(1,0);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the output pictures are normal and consistant again,
[image]

is there anything special about the commented line, or that is just a bug somehow? i was think of exploiting that to change the arrow tip color only without resorting to the advanced `decoration` option. now it seems that changing color of `angle 45` type arrow tip is indeed trickier than `latex`/`stealth` type.

Comment: Can you try the commented line without the empty `[]` and also converting `draw` to `path`?

Comment: I understand there's no real color stack in .dvi viewers (which one are you using?), which may (or may not) be related to your problem.

Comment: @percusse, thanks for the suggestion. if i changd the commented line into `\draw(0,-0.4)--++(1,0);` the problem still exists, it is the same as `\draw(0,-0.4)--++(1,0);` if i try `\path(0,-0.4)--++(1,0);` nothing is drawn for this line of code as expected, since the `draw` option is not specified. i guess div will be obsolete in the future?

Comment: @Koji, i used `Yap`. the color stack stuff are really stranger to me, but i'll test the result on linux later. thanks very much!

Comment: I expand: dvi files do not contain any color or grahics _per se_; what they can contain are `special`s. These `special`s are there for the benefit of post processing backend software; like dvips, dvipdfm or the integrated pdf backend of pdflatex. However, many dvi viewers will give it a shot to interpret _some_ `specials`. Color changes are hard to implement, you need a whole `color stack` to pop and push colors at the appropriate moments (consider a color change inside floating material). Hence, many dvi viewers fail _some_ of the time. Finally, tikz is really meant only for pdf/ps, not dvi.

Comment: @Koji, thanks very much for the explanation. i tested the code on linux, and `xdvi` showed the same problem. i think i'd better avoid div in the future if i draw pictures via latex. as i learned just now, `tikz+dvi+png` is broken and preview in dvi mode is unavailable. also in `standalone` class the inverse search is not working. in pdf mode, everthing works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

CW from the comments:

`.dvi` files do not contain any color or graphics *per se*; what they can contain are `special`s. These `special`s are there for the benefit of post-processing backend software; like `dvips`, `dvipdfm` or the integrated `pdf` backend of `pdflatex`.

However, many `dvi` viewers will give it a shot to interpret *some* `special`s. Color changes are hard to implement, you need a whole color stack to pop and push colors at the appropriate moments (consider a color change inside floating material). Hence, many `dvi` viewers fail *some* of the time. Finally, Tikz is really meant only for `pdf`/`ps`, not `dvi`.